# Tablet design and other screen sizes

Tags: android, tablet, screen-size, aide

I've been using Aide to develop my android app, a. Having issues designing for multiple screens and Especially tablets, cos I am using an handset not a tablet... how will I know the size

Comment: [Check here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Supporting Tablets and Handsets https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: If you using Aide then it would be hard to preview large screens because your using a handset, I would suggest you create two new layouts `layout-xlarge` and `layout-large` large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp and xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp, just duplicate the smaller layout and create separate `dimen.xml` for those larger screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through this link: hope we will get your solution

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The question is as direct as it can be, I jus need to know how to design for tablets using AIDE